# Are they in apposition?

Tags: grammar

> One afternoon, I saw that a group of journalists had gathered in a cluster in the lobby. From a distance and over their heads and outstretched devices, I saw Kees, standing at the center. He was gesticulating to the assembled crowd and I saw the conviction with which he relayed his message, everything was calculated, from the way he looked into the camera to *the way he made eye contact with the individual journalists*, **the careful articulation as he brought his thumb and index finger together, then splayed the fingers out in a single sweeping movement of muted, respectful triumph**.

Source: Intimacies: A New York Times Top 10 Book of 2021 By Katie Kitamura

Are "*the way he made eye contact with the individual journalists*" and "**the careful articulation as he brought his thumb and index finger together, then splayed the fingers out in a single sweeping movement of muted, respectful triumph**" in apposition?

Comment: [**apposition**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apposition) *a grammatical construction in which a noun or noun equivalent is followed by another that explains it. in "my friend the doctor," the word "doctor" is in apposition with "friend"*. So no - ***the way he made eye contact*** and ***the careful articulation*** are ***not*** "in apposition", because they're not just two different descriptions of the same action (or in the more common case, two different noun phrases referring to the same single real-world entity),

Comment: Maybe it's not precisely grammatical, similar to newspaper headlines. Sentence fragments, words missing.